# UNNotificationCategory subclass init issue

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, usernotifications, convenience-methods

I want to subclass `UNNotificationCategory`(UserNotifications), because I want to use enums instead of hard coded strings as category identifiers.
There is one convenience init inside `UNNotificationCategory` definition

```
public convenience init(identifier: String, actions: [UNNotificationAction], intentIdentifiers: [String], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions = [])
```

I am not able to write an initializer for my subclass. 
I understand I cant have designated initializer inside the subclass because I want to call the convenience init of superclass. But my convenience init is also throwing complier error.

Here's the code:

```
enum PushNotificationCategoryIdentifier:String {
}    

convenience init(categoryIdentifier:PushNotificationCategoryIdentifier, actions:[UNNotificationAction], intentIdentifiers:[String], options: UNNotificationCategoryOptions) {
            self.init(identifier: categoryIdentifier.rawValue, actions: actions, intentIdentifiers: intentIdentifiers, options: options)
        }
```

This is resulting in error: **self.init isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer**

I guess this is because this class is implemented in Objective-C and may be they have not called the designated initailizer from convenience initailizer(as Objective-C classes dont have to call designated initializer from convenience initailizer).

But does that mean I can't subclass `UNNotificationCategory` if I want to write an initializer in it?

Answer (score 0):

No you can do this. You will have to define `init()` method for this. Right now you have only defined `convenience init()`. But you will have to define `init()`in your subclass. 
When you write a `convenience init()` it is only there to help initialization in an easy way but still you will have to call designated init with syntax `init()` from the `convenience init()`. 
You can read it on [Apple Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Comment: Defining init with what? I cant initialize UNNotificationCategory variables as all are get only properties.